# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function on calling 3 different tables on same page with autorefresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datatables

this is my first time using scripts and i am trying to load 3 different tables to my web page all populated from mysql database. Also i want all 3 tables to refresh automaticlly when new data is inserted/changed. So far i managed to get all 3 tables to show with correct data however they do not refresh until i press f5 which is not good for me. All i can see is i have 1 error on all 3 tables:

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function

Here is also my code. Ofcourse any suggestion about the code are most welcome.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script> 

        <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
                                        setTimeout(function() { 
                                            $('#mainResults').load('tecaji_okp.php');
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                                $('#mainResults').DataTable();
                                            },1000);
                                        }, 1000);
                                    });

                                </script>
                                    <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
                                        setTimeout(function() { 
                                            $('#mainResults1').load('tecaji_ops.php');
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                                $('#mainResults1').DataTable();
                                            },1000);
                                        }, 1000);
                                    });

                                </script>
                                    <script>
                                    $(document).ready(function() {
                                        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
                                        setTimeout(function() { 
                                            $('#mainResults2').load('tecaji_ods.php');
                                            setTimeout(function(){
                                                $('#mainResults2').DataTable();
                                            },1000);
                                        }, 1000);
                                    });

                                </script>
```

And here is when i display them:

```
                        <div class="span6">
                        <div id="results">
                            <p>Online klinični primeri</p>
                            <table id="mainResults">
                                <td>
                                    Nalagam Online klinične primere ...</td>
                            </table>
                        </div></div>
                            <div class="span6">
                        <div id="results1">
                            <p>Online priprave na strokovni izpit</p>
                            <table id="mainResults1">
                                <td>
                                    Nalagam Online prirave na strokovni izpit ...</td>
                            </table>
                        </div></div>
                            <div class="span6">
                        <div id="results2">
                             <p>Online delavnice za študente medicine</p>
                            <table id="mainResults2">
                                <td>
                                    Nalagam Online delavnice za študente medicine ...</td>
                            </table>
                        </div></div>

                    </section>
```

Comment: I am wondering if you have jQuery more than once on the page.

Comment: Hi @Taplar i use from here: https://datatables.net/

Comment: Hi managed to get it to work, first problem was that i was having 2 Jquery on same page, then i needed to add <thead> to the table for the second problem. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

#### POSSIBLE CAUSES

- jQuery DataTables library is missing
- jQuery library is loaded **after** jQuery DataTables
- Multiple versions of jQuery library is loaded

Also your tables don't have proper structure. They should have at least 'thead' element with proper number of columns.

#### SOLUTION

Include only one version of jQuery library version 1.7 or newer **before** jQuery DataTables.

#### LINKS

Please see [jQuery DataTables: Common JavaScript console errors - TypeError: $(…).DataTable is not a function](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-common-javascript-console-errors/#typeerror-datatable-is-not-a-function) for more information.